# @Value Won't Pick Up Data

Tags: spring

In a controller, I have something like

```
@Value("${api.host.baseurl}")
private String baseurl;
```

and in a configration file application.yml, I have

```
api:
  host:   
    baseurl: localhost:3000/api/v1
```

The @Value doesn't pick the data up in the controller, however.

Update:

I didn't make my question clear in my original post. The data is picked in one environment (dev), but not in the other environment (prod). Why? Those configuration files are set up by JHipster, BTW.

Comment: Do you have any `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` somewhere or `@PropertySource` in your Controlelr?

Answer (score 0):

Annotating your controller class with @Configuration should fix the issue

or

```
@Value("${api.host.baseurl:localhost:3000/api/v1}")
private String baseurl;
```

Comment: The default value can prevent the error due to missing the property data during the application startup. It is basically hard-coded data if the property value can't be picked up.

Comment: What's the point having it in property file if you hard code it in your code. And application should fail only because these properties are missing and not because they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of these reason,

First reason can be `application.yml` (or `application.property`) file. Since loading property file can be changed when active profile is changed, make sure this property is available in both `dev` and `prod` property files. Since you have mentioned that *"data is picked in one environment (dev), but not in the other environment (prod)"*, this is can be the reason.

`@value` can inject values to you class only if that is a **spring bean**. If it is a simple POJO, then value will not be injected. Since you have mentioned that you have used this inside a controller (controller means this class is annotated by `@RestController` or `@Controller`) and worked in `dev` environment, this cannot be the reason.

#### Update

Its quite difficult to assume what is the issue without knowing all the facts. This is what I think. If your whole `application-prod.yml` is ignored in `prod` environment, issue should be passing active profile. For debug that you can check the application log inside your container. If profile is detected their should be a log like this,

```
ray.ApplicationMainClass       : The following profiles are active: prod
```

If active profile is not correctly set, log will be,

```
ray.ApplicationMainClass       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

**It will be helpful to know how you set active profile in `prod` env.**

If issue only there for `api.host.baseurl: localhost:3000/api/v1` propety, then issue should be the property itself.

Comment: I don't quite follow your first point. There are three configuration files: application.yml, application-dev.yml, and application-prod.yml. The particular property is defined in both application-prod.yml and application-dev.yml files. The problem shows up when the application is deployed in a docker container as the production environment.

Comment: If this particular property in both property files, then it should be fine. You have mentioned that *"@Value doesn't pick the data up"*. So your application fails during the startup right?

Comment: That is correct. I have to add a default value to prevent that the app fails to start.

Comment: So your whole `application-prod.yml` is ignored in `prod` env! Have you pass what is active profile as an `environment variable` in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: a good point. I forgot to check it with our operation person. The app doesn't use Docker file for docker.

Comment: @vic great! Keep me posted.

Comment: The DevOps person says that he started the app for the production profile.

Comment: @vic okay! Another thing that can happen is your `yml` is not formatted correctly. May be a simple space is missing! Try to validate `application-prod.yml` using any validation tool. You can use [this](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator)

Comment: Thanks for the format check information. I know the indent can easily cause problems in a Yaml file. The format seems to be correct to me.

Comment: Thanks very much for your update. Our DevOp person has a look at the production log messages but doesn't see the line of log messages. I search it on my local deployment and don't see it either. What log level the log message?

Comment: It is `INFO` level. It should be one of the first application log message.